# Como esta codificado un archivo .docx

Tags: docx

Quiero hacer un conversor de .docx a html, se que hay muchos pero yo quiero aprender. EL problema es que no se donde y como obtener informacion, si pudiera entender como esta conformao el codigo de un documento docx podria implementar una manera de hacer un html basado en ese archivo.
Quiero saber como se codifican estos archivos y tambien si eso se podria hacer usando javascript?
o golang

Comment: Atravez de linux he podido ver que un archivo `.docx` se empaqueta como zip pero al momento de ejecutarse word lo interpreta directamente traduciendo todo ese contenido a un documento de word, en los archivos que he visto se usa xml, mas al parecer es lo unico que hay entre otros archivos de configuracion y reglas, de todas maneras esta informacion considero que es casi inutil debido al simple hecho de que se necesitara algo especial de microsoft para poder exportar a ese formato de manera adecuada, de lo contrario crear algo asi no solo seria muy complejo, si no que tambien muy extenso.

Comment: Por cierto, me parece una pregunta interesante, pero el problema son 2 cosas: 1 la pregunta es muy extensa y 2 el sitio no funciona asi, nosotros resolvemos dudas acerca de un codigo que tengas y en base a algo que hayas intentado, por ejemplo supongamos una tecnologia x que sirve para ese proposito que indicas y que para ello se puede usar JS, entonces deberas haber intentado algo atravez de javascript usando esa tecnologia en codigo y haber puesto tu codigo aqui, especificando no solamente aquello que deseas lograr de manera clara o que es lo que no esta funcionando en el codigo.

Comment: Dicho esto te dire que es buena idea que te pases por el [tour] y que leas tambien sobre [ask].

Comment: No-respuesta: Encontraste la principal dificultad para abrir esos archivos en otros editores; la documentación es pobrísima y no siempre adhieren a OOXML..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La extensión de archivo `.docx` se utiliza generalmente en archivos de Microsoft Word® que tienen el formato [Office Open XML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML#ISO/IEC_29500:2008), que es un estándar de la industria propuesto originalmente por Microsoft y adaptado a algunas recomendaciones del comité que se creó para el efecto.

Como estándar, está bastante bien documentado de manera pública en los siguientes documentos:

- [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)
- [ISO/IEC 29500:2008](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=45374) (que tiene 4 partes).

Dicho esto, comentar que

- Un archivo `.docx` es básicamente un archivo `.zip` que contiene en su interior una serie de carpetas, documentos `.xml` y puede potencialmente tener imágenes, videos y otros multimedios que forman parte del "documento", sus secciones y contenido.
- Su estructura, aunque bastante bien documentada, es compleja y realizar un intérprete de este tipo de archivos para cualquier procesamiento (por ejemplo generar un HTML) diría que no es un proyecto de unas pocas horas de programación. (Solo leer la documentación y hacerse una idea del contenido puede llevar un tiempo considerable).
- No es el único formato para documentos y, de hecho, es uno de los más criticados de la industria.

Comment: Nota menor: Microsoft hizo todo lo posible por sabotear OOXML y procuró incluir características por fuera del estándar. Algo perderás siempre al abrir un docx en otro editor.